# How do I link these multiple functions together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, react-hooks

I am trying to do multiple things in one function. I need them all to happen one after another when I submit the form

```
1. Get back data (here is where the meals array is set)
2. Check the length of the meals array
3. Append a slide if the length of the array is longer than 1
4. Slide to that new slide if meals length is indeed greater than 1
```

I am trying callbacks & async functions and it is still not working. When the form is submitted the meals array is set. Then if I submit again, the meals length array is checked and the slide is appended if the if/else statement is true.

Please help me! I will take any solution that works - promises, callbacks, etc.

Here is the code for the first function:

```
const handleSearch = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    if (searchVal.trim() !== '') {
        let foodSearch = searchVal.trim().replace(/ /g, '+')
        databaseFetch(`${BASE_URL}search.php?s=${foodSearch}`)
        secondFunction()
    } else {
        setSearchVal('')
    }       
}
```

And here is second function:

```
function secondFunction() {
    if (meals.length > 1) {
        slide1Horizontal.appendSlide(`<div class="swiper-slide">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<SearchResults />)}</div>`)
        slide1Horizontal.slideTo(2, 1000)
    }
```

Here is the original fetch function:

```
const databaseFetch = async foodToSearch => {
    setLoading(true)

    let returned = await (await fetch(foodToSearch));

    if (returned.ok) {
        let result = await returned.json()
        //console.log(result)
        setMeals(
            result.meals !== null   
                ? [...result.meals]
                : []
        )
        //console.log(meals)
    } else {
        setError({
            error: true,
            statusCode: returned.status,
            statusText: returned.statusText
        })
    }
    setLoading(false)
}

}
```

Comment: What is `setMeals` and what is the scope of the `meals` variable?

Comment: I am using React Hooks

Answer (score 1):

You seems that you need to make your handleSearch function as an async function, and await for your DB fetch by using the async/await syntax.

https://javascript.info/async-await

What also seems to be the problem is that you are referencing the stateful variable 'meals' in the same function that it is set and you are expecting to have the updated value. What you need to do is return meals in the databaseFetch component, then pass the returned value of databaseFetch down to the secondFunction as a parameter. That should give you your updated value

```
const handleSearch = (e) => {

e.preventDefault();

if (searchVal.trim() !== '') {
    let foodSearch = searchVal.trim().replace(/ /g, '+')
    databaseFetch(`${BASE_URL}search.php?s=${foodSearch}`)
    secondFunction()
} else {
    setSearchVal('')
}       


const databaseFetch = async foodToSearch => {
setLoading(true)

let returned = await (await fetch(foodToSearch));

if (returned.ok) {
    let result = await returned.json()
    //console.log(result)
    return (
        result.meals !== null   
            ? [...result.meals]
            : []
    )
    //console.log(meals)
} else {
    setError({
        error: true,
        statusCode: returned.status,
        statusText: returned.statusText
    })
}
setLoading(false)}

function secondFunction(mealsFromDb) {
if (mealsFromDb.length > 1) {
    slide1Horizontal.appendSlide(`<div class="swiper-slide">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<SearchResults />)}</div>`)
    slide1Horizontal.slideTo(2, 1000)
}
```

Comment: This solution produces the same problem.

Comment: Same result. Whenever I submit the form the meals array is lagging 1 iteration behind.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add the second function on the database fetch?

```
const databaseFetch = async foodToSearch => {
setLoading(true)

let returned = await (await fetch(foodToSearch));

if (returned.ok) {
   let result = await returned.json()
   // ADD SECOND FUNCTION HERE TO ENSURE THAT IT RUNS AFTER DATA FETCH
   secondFunction(result);
   return (
     result.meals !== null   
        ? [...result.meals]
        : []
  )
  //console.log(meals)
 } else {
   setError({
      error: true,
      statusCode: returned.status,
      statusText: returned.statusText
})
}
setLoading(false)}
```